# How to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(2n+3)}=\ln(2)-1/2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How i can prove that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(2n+3)}=\ln(2)-1/2
$$

And
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(4n+1)(4n+2)(4n+3)(4n+4)}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\ln(2) - \frac{\pi}{6}\right).
$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Have you tried anything and can share your thoughts and attempts? Regards

Comment: The first sum is $\ln\left(2\right) - 2/3$. When the $n$-index start at $0$, the result is $\ln\left(2\right) - 1/2$. See my answer. I didn't check the second one.

Answer (score 17):

An alternative approach; compute

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n+3}}{(2n+3)(2n+2)(2n+1)}$$

This has the property that $f'''(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$. Integrate once  (partial fractions) to get logarithms. Integrate twice more (by parts) and evaluate at 1 to get the answer $f(1)$.

Comment: +1. This is a nice and probably an easier approach than mine, though the reason why both work are similar if not the same.

Comment: Absolutely! I started writing "ultimately equivalent to the other answer" but then thought this would merit extra discussion so I left it out, being lazy...

Answer (score 13):

I assume both your summation starts from $0$ instead of $1$.
We have
$$a_n = \dfrac1{(2n+1)(2n+2)(2n+3)} = \dfrac1{2(2n+1)} + \dfrac1{2(2n+3)} - \dfrac1{2n+2}$$
This gives us
$$a_n = \dfrac12 \int_0^1x^{2n} dx + \dfrac12 \int_0^1x^{2n+2} dx - \int_0^1 x^{2n+1} dx = \dfrac12 \int_0^1 x^{2n}(1-x)^2dx$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = \dfrac12 \int_0^1 \dfrac{(1-x)^2}{1-x^2}dx = \dfrac12 \int_0^1 \dfrac{1-x}{1+x}dx = \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{1+x} - \dfrac12 \int_0^1dx = \log(2) - \dfrac12$$
The same idea works for the other series as well and I will leave it to you to work out the details. **Be careful on two counts**, while following the above technique:

$1$. Note that I wrote $\dfrac1{2n+2}$ as $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{2n+1} dx$ and not as $\displaystyle \dfrac12 \int_0^1 x^n dx$. Though both are valid ways to obtain $\dfrac1{2n+2}$, if you do the second way, when you sum it up, you are changing the order of summation and hence will get a different **incorrect** answer.

$2$. Also, make sure to justify the change of integration and limits.

Answer (score 12):

This is similar, but without partial fractions!

$$(1)$$

$$  \begin{aligned}  \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)(2n+3)}  & =\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\Gamma(2n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+4)} \\& =\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{B}(2n+1, \,3) \\& = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}(1-x)^2\; dx\\& = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1-x}{1+x} \;{dx}  \\& = \ln 2-\frac{1}{2} \end{aligned}$$

$$(2)$$

$$  \begin{aligned}  \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(4n+1)(4n+2)(4n+3)(4n+4)}  & =\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\Gamma(4n+1)}{\Gamma(4n+5)} \\& =\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{6}\mathrm{B}(4n+1, \,4) \\& = \frac{1}{6}\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{1}x^{4n}(1-x)^3\; dx\\& = \frac{1}{6}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(1-x)^2}{(1+x^2)(1+x)} \; dx  \\& = \frac{\ln 2}{4}-\frac{\pi}{24} \end{aligned}$$

Comment: +1. This is neat. Slightly circumvents the possible mistake of rearranging sums, that could happen in my method.

Comment: @user17762 Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(2n+1)(2n+2)(2n+3)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1/2}{2n+1}+\frac{-1}{2n+2}+\frac{1/2}{2n+3}\right)\\
&=-\frac{\frac12}{1}+\frac{\frac12}{1}\tag{add $0$}\\
&\hphantom{=-\frac{\frac12}{1}}+\frac{\frac12}{1}-\frac12+\frac{\frac12}{3}\tag{$n=0$}\\
&\hphantom{=-\frac{\frac12}{1}+\frac{\frac12}{1}-\frac12}+\frac{\frac12}{3}-\frac14+\frac{\frac12}{5}\tag{$n=1$}\\
&\hphantom{=-\frac{\frac12}{1}+\frac{\frac12}{1}-\frac12+\frac{\frac12}{3}-\frac14}+\frac{\frac12}{5}-\frac16+\dots\tag{$n=2$}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{-\frac12}+\color{#00A000}{1-\frac12\,+\frac13-\frac14+\frac15-\frac16+\dots}\\
&=\color{#00A000}{\log(2)}\color{#C00000}{-\frac12}
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(4n+1)(4n+2)(4n+3)(4n+4)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1/6}{4n+1}+\frac{-1/2}{4n+2}+\frac{1/2}{4n+3}+\frac{-1/6}{4n+4}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1/6}{4n+1}+\frac{1/6}{4n+3}\right)+\left(\frac{1/3}{4n+1}+\frac{1/3}{4n+3}\right)\\
&\hphantom{\sum_{n=0}^\infty}+\left(\frac{-1/6}{4n+2}+\frac{1/6}{4n+4}\right)+\left(\frac{-1/3}{4n+2}+\frac{-1/3}{4n+4}\right)\\
&=\color{#00A000}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1/6}{4n+1}+\frac{1/6}{4n+3}\right)}+\color{#0000FF}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1/6}{4n+2}+\frac{1/6}{4n+4}\right)}\\
&+\color{#C00000}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1/3}{4n+1}+\frac{1/3}{4n+3}\right)+\left(\frac{-1/3}{4n+2}+\frac{-1/3}{4n+4}\right)}\\
&=\color{#00A000}{-\frac\pi{24}}\color{#0000FF}{-\frac{\log(2)}{12}}\\
&\color{#C00000}{+\frac{\log(2)}{3}}\\
&=\frac{\log(2)}{4}-\frac\pi{24}
\end{align}
$$
[$\color{#00A000}{\text{Leibniz Series}}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_series), [$\color{#0000FF}{\text{Alternating Harmonic Series}}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Alternating_harmonic_series), and $\color{#C00000}{\text{Alternating Harmonic Series}}$.

Comment: I am not completely sure but looks like you are rearranging terms for the second summation (?)

Comment: @user17762: sure, but only splitting a block of four terms into a block of eight term, then reorganizing the block of eight. All of it perfectly fine.

Comment: In the following line $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1/6}{4n+1}+\frac{1/6}{4n+3}\right)+\left(\frac{1/3}{4n+1}+\frac{1/3}{4n+3}\right)\\
+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1/6}{4n+2}+\frac{1/6}{4n+4}\right)+\left(\frac{-1/3}{4n+2}+\frac{-1/3}{4n+4}\right)$$ both the individual sums are $\infty$ (?).

Comment: @user17762: I was too exuberant with my sigmas. It should have been one sum broken over two lines.

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align}
&\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \left(2n + 1\right)\left(2n + 2\right)\left(2n + 3\right)}
=
{1 \over 4}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\left({1 \over n + 1/2} - {2 \over n + 1} + {1 \over n + 3/2}\right)
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 8}\left\lbrack
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \left(n + 1/2\right)\left(n + 1\right)}
-
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \left(n + 1\right)\left(n + 3/2\right)}
\right\rbrack
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 8}\left\lbrack
{\Psi\left(1/2\right) - \Psi\left(1\right) \over 1/2 - 1}
-
{\Psi\left(1\right) - \Psi\left(3/2\right) \over 1 - 3/2}
\right\rbrack
=
{1 \over 4}\left\lbrack - \Psi\left(1 \over 2\right) + 2\Psi\left(1\right)
-
\Psi\left(3 \over 2\right)
\right\rbrack
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 4}\left\lbrace
-\Psi\left(1 \over 2\right) + 2\Psi\left(1\right)
-
\left\lbrack 2 + \Psi\left(1 \over 2\right)\right\rbrack
\right\rbrace
=
{1 \over 2}\left\lbrack
-\Psi\left(1 \over 2\right) + \Psi\left(1\right) - 1
\right\rbrack
\\[3mm]&=
{1 \over 2}\left\lbrace
-\left\lbrack-\gamma - 2\ln\left(2\right)\right\rbrack
+
\left(-\gamma\right) - 1
\right\rbrace
=
\ln\left(2\right) - {1 \over 2}
\\[1cm]&
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \left(2n + 1\right)\left(2n + 2\right)\left(2n + 3\right)}
&=
\ln\left(2\right) - {1 \over 2}
\\[3mm]
\color{#0000FF}{\large\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over \left(2n + 1\right)\left(2n + 2\right)\left(2n + 3\right)}}
&=
\left\lbrack\ln\left(2\right) - {1 \over 2}\right\rbrack - {1 \over 6}
=
\color{#0000ff}{\large \ln\left(2\right) - {2 \over 3}}
\\[1cm]&
\end{align}

$\Psi\left(z\right)$ is the Digamma function and
$\gamma = 0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215933593992\ldots$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.