# How do we evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We have to evaulate $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k}$$
I have tried to expand it to see some kind of pattern, but there seems to be no obvious one! Then I tried to just mindlessly integrate and after solving the integral $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k} dk$ the answer came to be $\frac{1}{3}\log(\frac{3}{2})$ which contrasts the answer from wolfram alpha by a significant margin which is $\frac{1}{18}(9\log3-\sqrt{3}\pi)$. 
I have found problems of similar kind on this site but I am not really able to understand them, specifically, how did this particular sum got converted into a gamma function (they don't seem to be related on the surface). 
I have some idea about gamma and beta function but please try to be as detailed as possible (at least for the conversion of the sum into integral part) with your solutions.

Comment: even hints would be helpful for the first part of conversion into integration

Comment: $$\frac1{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k}=\int_0^1 (x^{3k-2}-x^{3k-1})\,dx$$

Comment: Then you get your sum is $$\int_0^1\frac{x\,dx}{1+x+x^2}$$

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAndrews but how did people convert this sum into gamma function still remains a mystery to me

Comment: "How did people..." What people! You first said you had the idea that it had something to do with $\Gamma,$ but you didn't say, "some people say," which is a very different statement.

Comment: I know general stuff about those functions, not in respect to this particular problem, the [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/476395/959605) on which I noticed this method being used is about 10 years old so it didn't seem reasonable to ask it there.

Comment: Yeah, that answer is sort of a leap into another mode of thinking, but then it gets back to the approach I have. There is no real reason to start using gamma and beta functions, unless that is intuitive to you. It is complete overkill here.

Comment: What's your idea on using the Gamma and Beta functions?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I agree that using Gamma and Beta functions is overkill and the same with Digamma functions as well. I have posted an answer using Digamma functions, but it's not intuitive at all and I find your method easier.

Comment: thank you everyone, for some weird reason I was just blind to the fact that $\Gamma (z+1) = z!$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews,not OP, but I'm struggling with similar questions, so I would love to know how you went from the sum to $x^{\frac{3k}{2}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think @ThomasAndrews' comment is worthy of becoming an answer in its own right.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}}\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k}\right)}&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{0}^1\left(x^{3k-2}-x^{3k-1}\right)dx\\
> &=\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(x^{3k+1}-x^{3k+2}\right)dx\tag{1.1}\\
> &=\int_{0}^1\left(\frac{x}{1-x^3}-\frac{x^2}{1-x^3}\right)dx\tag{1.2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\int_{0}^1\frac{x}{1+x+x^2}dx}\tag{1.3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1.1) we exchange sum and integral and shift the index of the sum to start with $k=0$.
- In (1.2) we apply the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Geometric_series,_exponential_function_and_sine)*.
- In (1.3) we use $1-x^3=(1-x)\left(1+x+x^2\right)$.

We derive from (1.3) by elementary transformations
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{I:=\int_{0}^1}&\color{blue}{\frac{x}{1+x+x^2}dx}\\
&=\int_{0}^1\frac{2x+1}{1+x+x^2}dx-\int_{0}^1\frac{1+x}{1+x+x^2}dx\\
&=\ln\left(1+x+x^2\right)\Big|_0^1-I-\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x+x^2}\\
&=\ln (3)-I-\int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{\frac{3}{4}+\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}\\
&=\ln (3)-I-\frac{4}{3}\int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{1+\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)^2}\\
&=\ln (3)-I-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\int_{1/\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{du}{1+u^2}\tag{2.1}\\
&=\ln (3)-I-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\left(\arctan\left(\sqrt{3}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)\\
&=\ln (3)-I-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\ln (3)-I-\frac{\pi}{9}\sqrt{3}}\tag{2.2}
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2.1) we substitute
  $
  u=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right), 
  du=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}dx
  $
  and set the limits of the integral accordingly.

> Putting (1.3) and (2.2) together we finally get
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}}&\color{blue}{\left(\frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k}\right)
> =\frac{1}{2}\ln (3)-\frac{\pi}{18}\sqrt{3}}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea using the [Digamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Let the given sum equal $S$. Consider the following manipulation:

$$
\eqalign{
S&=\displaystyle\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k}\right) \cr
&= -\dfrac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k-\frac{1}{3}}\right) - \gamma + \gamma\right) \cr 
&= -\dfrac{1}{3}\left(\psi\left(-\frac{1}{3}+1\right)+\gamma\right), \cr
}
$$

where we used the formula

$$\psi(s+1) = \sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+s}\right) - \gamma.$$

One of Gauss's formulas relates values of the Digamma function for $r,m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $r < m$ to some elementary functions. Specifically,

$$\psi\left(\dfrac{r}{m}\right) = -\gamma - \ln(2m) -\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{r\pi}{m}\right)+2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{\frac{m-1}{2}\rfloor}}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi kr}{m}\right)\ln\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{m}\right)\right).$$

Rewriting $\psi\left(-\frac{1}{3}-1\right)$ as $\psi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$, we get

$$\psi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) = -\gamma - \ln(2 \cdot 3) -\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)+2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{\frac{3-1}{2}\rfloor}}\cos\left(\frac{2\pi k2}{3}\right)\ln\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{3}\right)\right),$$

which simplifies down to

$$-\gamma -\ln\left(6\right)+\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{6}-\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right).$$

Plugging it back into $S$ and simplifying, we ultimately get

$$S = \ln\left(\sqrt{3}\right)-\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{3}}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Let
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}( \frac{1}{3k-1}-\frac{1}{3k})x^{3k}.$$
Then
$$ f’(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3k-1}x^{3k-1}, f’’(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{3k-2}=\frac{x}{1-x^3}$$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
f(1)&=&\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{y}{1-y^3}dydx=\int_0^1\int_y^1\frac{y}{1-y^3}dxdy\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{(1-y)y}{1-y^3}dy=\int_0^1\frac{y}{y^2+y+1}dy\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac{(y+\frac12)-\frac12}{(y+\frac12)^2+(\frac{\sqrt3}2)^2}dy\\
&=&\frac12\ln((y+\frac12)^2+(\frac{\sqrt3}2)^2)-\sqrt3\arctan(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt3})\bigg|_0^1\\
&=&\frac12\ln3-\frac{\sqrt3\pi}{18}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: crazy thought process, thanks a lot for this unique answer!!